# normal samples' expected value

Tags: statistics

Let $X_i$ be a random sample of $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.
Each sample has value of one if $X_i >p$ and otherwise it has value of zero.
Now, we select all $N$ available samples and calculate this

$$\sum_{i=1}^N (1\Pr(X_i >p))$$

Does the above show the expected value of the $N$ samples?

The samples are independent and have identical distribution.

Can we solve the above as below, considering that $X$ is a random variable of $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$?

$$\sum_{i=1}^N (1\Pr(X_i >p))=N \Pr(X >p) = N\left(1-\Phi\left(\frac{p-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right)$$

Comment: You are using the word "sample" incorrectly. The entire sequence of observations $X_1,\ldots,X_N$ is one sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather not speak of random samples but of [random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Definition) $X_1,\dots,X_N$ that are defined on the same [probability space.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space#Definition)

Then we can define $B_i:=1_{(b,\infty)}(X_i)$ for each $i\in\{1,\dots,N\}$ and defined like that the $B_i$ are also random variables defined on that space.

Further it is evident that $B_i$ only takes values in $\{0,1\}$ so that: $$\mathbb EB_i=0\cdot P(B_i=0)+1\cdot P(B_i=1)=P(X_i>b)$$The last equality on base of: $$\{B_i=1\}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid B_i(\omega)=1\}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X_i(\omega)>p\}=\{X_i>p\}$$

If $B:=B_1+\cdots+B_N$ then with linearity of expectation we find:$$\mathbb EB=\mathbb E\sum_{i=1}^NB_i=\sum_{i=1}^N\mathbb EB_i=\sum_{i=1}^NP(X_i>p)\tag1$$

This equality also holds if the $B_i$ are not independent.

If the $X_i$ have a common distribution then so do the $B_i$ and $(1)$ simplifies to: $$\mathbb EB=NP(X_1>p)\tag2$$

If this distribution is the normal distribution with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ then we can write $X_1=\sigma U+\mu$ where $U$ has standard normal distribution so that $$P(X_1>p)=P(\sigma U+\mu>p)=P\left(U>\frac{p-\mu}{\sigma}\right)=1-\Phi\left(\frac{p-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$$ and we end up with:$$\mathbb EB=N\left(1-\Phi\left(\frac{p-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right)\tag3$$

Used is now that the $X_i$ are defined on the same probability space and all have the same distribution which is the normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Independence is not necessary to achieve this result.

Comment: Thank you very much for this awesome explanation.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: You are right to reject the term "random samples" but you fail to identify the reason why that is wrong. The whole sequence $(X_1,\ldots,X_N)$ is a sample, the individual random variables within it are not samples.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for filling up the omission. For me personally "random sample" is badly framed and multi-interpretable. A definition in nLab lacks, and the one on Wikipedia is narrow. I strive to pass on knowledge and not too much own interpretations, so decided to avoid the concept.